# How can I deserialize this JSON format using restsharp? (c#)

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

How should my classes look like so that I can deserialize the JSON below.

```
{
    "Bob": [{
            "code": "Bob",
            "tier": 1
        },
        {
            "code": "Bob",
            "tier": 2
        }
    ],
    "Joe": [{
            "code": "Joe",
            "tier": 1
        },
        {
            "code": "Joe",
            "tier": 2
    }

    ]
     }
```

The classes below (from json2csharp.com) works but when my json has lots of different names this is not going to scale as I will end up with 100+ classes.

```
public class Bob
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int tier { get; set; }
}

public class Joe
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int tier { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Bob> Bob { get; set; }
    public List<Joe> Joe { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas would help me here.(I have tried using a dictionary and a dynamic list)

Comment: Bob and Joe could inherit from the same base class... Although I think you might need to rethink how your classes are defined. Bob and Joe are the same so how about you just have one class Student or Person instead.

Comment: Can you modify the JSON to have `Bob` and `Joe` be objects in an array?

Comment: No, the bob and joe were an example, I am using data from a private api that can not be changed.  The actual json has more variables in the class.  It is in the same format though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the structure of your JSON, then you can try to use a Dictionary instead of classes that are named according to their JSON property names. E.g.

```
public class Person {
    public string code {get; set; }
    public int tier {get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize the JSON not as `RootObject` but as `Dictionary<string, List<Person>>`